# How to display each input data in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a controller called `insert`. Which is defined like this

```
class InsertController < ApplicationController
    def create
    end
    def show
        render plain: params[:insert].inspect
    end
end
```

My `create.html.erb` file is defined like this

```
<%= form_for :insert, url: '/insert/show' do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :fname, placeholder: "Enter First Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :lname, placeholder: "Enter Last Name" %><br />
    <%= f.submit "Login"%>
<% end %>
```

`routes.rb` is as follows

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get '' => 'greeter#hello'
    get 'new' => 'insert#create'
    post 'insert/show' => 'insert#show'
end
```

When I am entering the form below

[image]

I am having this output

[image]

Till now no issues. But I want to render the output like this

[image]

What is the way to access those **hash key-value pair**?
I have seen examples where they are first storing these data to database and then from database they are fetching these. Is it possible to show these value like my intended output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `show.html.erb` file

```
<%= debug(params) %>
```

And change your show action to just empty method

```
def show
end
```

`debug` method will display params hash with more human readable way.

Comment: At `show.html.erb` page I wrote `First Name: <%= params[:insert][:fname] %> Last Name: <%= params[:insert][:lname] %>`. The `debug` method was showing a lot of info which I didn't want. I got the logic behind that data transfer from a form to a action and from the action to a view using this nested hashmaps. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ParnabSanyal Cool, I assumed that you may want to display more parameters later.

Comment: That was thoughtful.